# SOQL or Apex to get package name and package license id of installed packages in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex, soql

In Salesforce, we have PackageLicense table which cotains namespaceprefix and package license id. There is possibility that namespaceprefix can be duplicate. In order to fetch the correct information, I am looking for SOQL query or apex code to fetch list of all installed packages. I am looking to fetch name, namespaceprefix and package license id in the query. I was unable to find a way to fetch the name of the package. Please advise.

Comment: You would get better answers from the folks at https://salesforce.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

Name currently isn't available in the InstalledPacakes object you would need to do a second query of the Publisher object to get the name and cross reference with the namespace prefix

```
[SELECT Id,NamespacePrefix,Status FROM PackageLicense]
[SELECT Name,NamespacePrefix FROM Publisher WHERE IsSalesforce = false]
```